# How to authenticate (user/password) proxy in c# selenium chrome driver

Tags: c#, google-chrome, selenium

I have a HTTP/HTTPS proxy which need to authenticate using username and password. How do I do that using C# selenium chrome webdriver?

```
string host = proxies[count].Split(':')[0];
int port = Convert.ToInt32(proxies[count].Split(':')[1]) + 1;

string prox = host + ":" + port.ToString();

OpenQA.Selenium.Proxy proxy = new OpenQA.Selenium.Proxy();
proxy.HttpProxy = prox;
proxy.SslProxy = prox;
options.Proxy = proxy;
```

options is the ChromeOptions class which I assign to the driver.

Comment: So what's the issue? You've got the code above, great, what's the issue with it?

Comment: It doesn't authenticate with username:password. I get a popup box in the chrome window to enter login info to use the proxy.

Comment: @lincher did you find any solution other than AutoIt or extension?

Answer (score 5):

I created little package for yor problem (https://github.com/RDavydenko/OpenQA.Selenium.Chrome.ChromeDriverExtensions)

Install Package:

```
Install-Package OpenQA.Selenium.Chrome.ChromeDriverExtensions -Version 1.2.0
```

Use for your `ChromeOptions`:

```
using OpenQA.Selenium;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Chrome;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Chrome.ChromeDriverExtensions;
...
var options = new ChromeOptions();

// Add your HTTP-Proxy
options.AddHttpProxy(PROXY_HOST, PROXY_PORT, PROXY_USER, PROXY_PASSWORD);

var driver = new ChromeDriver(options); // or new ChromeDriver(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, options);

driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("https://whatismyipaddress.com/"); // Check your IP
```

Instead of `PROXY_HOST, PROXY_PORT, PROXY_USER, PROXY_PASSWORD`, use the parameters of your proxy

Comment: It worked great for me!
The only issue are the error messages I'm getting in console window:

`DevTools listening on ws://127.0.0.1:22181/devtools/browser/e8645bd1-cf29-43d4-88d8-bbc3082006c3`, 
`[32116:13020:0820/192007.167:ERROR:device_event_log_impl.cc(214)] [19:20:07.166] USB: usb_device_handle_win.cc:1048 Failed to read descriptor from node connection: A device attached to the system is not functioning. (0x1F)` and
`[26420:27692:0820/192024.445:ERROR:ssl_client_socket_impl.cc(981)] handshake failed; returned -1, SSL error code 1, net_error -113`

Just ignore them?

Comment: It gives an error: "-  unknown error: failed to wait for extension background page to load: chrome-extension://nkafcmingnfckmeoffkalgicjckfghaj/_generated_background_page.html
from unknown error: page could not be found: chrome-extension://nkafcmingnfckmeoffkalgicjckfghaj/_generated_background_page.html"

Comment: Found the reason why it fails on mine: it uses a plugin. Make sure not to use an option --incognito and --disable-extensions.

Comment: useless in headless mode, same as @DavidPiao, background page to load: chrome-extension://nkafcmingnfckmeoffkalgicjckfghaj/_generated_background_page.html from unknown error: page could not be found

Answer (score 2):

The only successful approach I have found is to use AutoIT ( https://www.autoitscript.com/site/autoit ).

I have mine setup for proxy authentication for all of the major browsers, but this should work for Chrome.
I wrote this on my phone from memory. If it doesn't work let me know and I'll correct.

```
WinWait("data:, - Google Chrome","","10")
If WinExists("data:, - Google Chrome","")Then
WinActivate("data:, - Google Chrome")
Send("USERNAMEGOESHERE"{TAB}")
Send("USERPASSWORDGOESHERE"{ENTER}")
```

Using AutoIT, create this as a script, compile it to exe, save it somewhere and reference the file with the following (Java code):

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("C:\\users\\USERID\\desktop\\FILENAME.exe");
```

I find it best to call the proxy script a step BEFORE you call the URL that triggers the proxy auth.

Comment: I've also had success with AutoIT, but found AutoIT has limitations when it comes to running on Selenium Grid.  If you aren't parallel-izing your test runs, @TheBear's solution should get you on track.

Answer (score 1):

**2019 Update**

After multiple unfortunate attempts, the easiest solution is to create an extension for Chrome as explained by Mike in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8885137/selenium-using-python-enter-provide-http-proxy-password-for-firefox/35293222#35293222) post.

It sounds freaky, but it is actually really straightforward.

Answer (score 1):

#### **2021 Update**

I have created a simple library ([nuget package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/SeleniumProxyAuth/)) that helps you with selenium proxy authentication. You can check the source at [Github repo](https://github.com/Erol444/SeleniumProxyAuth). It also works when using driver headless.

**Usage:**

```cs
public void Test()
{  
    // Create a local proxy server
    var proxyServer = new SeleniumProxyAuth();

    // Don't await, have multiple drivers at once using the local proxy server
    TestSeleniumProxyServer(proxyServer, new ProxyAuth("123.123.123.123", 80, "prox-username1", "proxy-password1"));
    TestSeleniumProxyServer(proxyServer, new ProxyAuth("11.22.33.44", 80, "prox-username2", "proxy-password2"));
    TestSeleniumProxyServer(proxyServer, new ProxyAuth("111.222.222.111", 80, "prox-username3", "proxy-password3"));

    while (true) { }
}

private async Task TestSeleniumProxyServer(SeleniumProxyAuth proxyServer, ProxyAuth auth)
{
    // Add a new local proxy server endpoint
    var localPort = proxyServer.AddEndpoint(auth);

    ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
    //options1.AddArguments("headless");

    // Configure the driver's proxy server to the local endpoint port
    options.AddArgument($"--proxy-server=127.0.0.1:{localPort}");

    // Optional
    var service = ChromeDriverService.CreateDefaultService();
    service.HideCommandPromptWindow = true;

    // Create the driver
    var driver = new ChromeDriver(service, options);

    // Test if the driver is working correctly
    driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("https://www.myip.com/");
    await Task.Delay(5000);
    driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("https://amibehindaproxy.com/");
    await Task.Delay(5000);

    // Dispose the driver
    driver.Dispose();
}
```

Comment: Hi! I used it so at first-time chrome blocked me saying you want to proceed? Advanced but I just couldn't get to the site. But the second third time site returns an empty value. Could you please help @Erik Kokalj

Comment: @PriyankaArora what do you mean chrome blocked you? If you don't need headless feature you can try to use the chrome extension for proxy auth

Answer (score 0):

This is for firefox but the top answer might help.

[C# Selenium WebDriver FireFox Profile - using proxy with Authentication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12186579/c-sharp-selenium-webdriver-firefox-profile-using-proxy-with-authentication)

What you can do is to create a profile and save the authentication data in it. If your profile is called "webdriver" you can select it from your code in the initialization:

```
ProfilesIni allProfiles = new ProfilesIni(); 
FirefoxProfile profile = allProfiles.getProfile("WebDriver"); 
profile.setPreferences("foo.bar",23);
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(profile);
```

Answer (score 0):

Chrome won't let you use any extension for selenium web testing these days. And selenium doesn't have any built in username & password input for proxies.

The only solution I found is using AutoIt. It will automates windows level actions. While selenium only automates browser level actions.

Passing username and password to the proxy dialog box is A WINDOWS LEVEL ACTION.

To download and install AutoIt, you can go to : https://www.guru99.com/use-autoit-selenium.html

I wrote a simple AutoIt script as below :

```
; option to read substring in a window title
Opt("WinTitleMatchMode", 2)

; wait for proxy username & password dialog box
WinWait("- Google Chrome","","10")

; if the box shows up, write the username and password
; username & password are passed as program parameters
If WinExists("- Google Chrome","") Then
    WinActivate("- Google Chrome")

    ; $CmdLine is a special array that holds parameters
    if $CmdLine[0] = 2 Then
        Send($CmdLine[1] & "{TAB}")
        Send($CmdLine[2] & "{ENTER}")
    EndIf

    ; any request dialog to save credential?
    WinWait("Save password for ","","10")

    ; if any, close it
    If WinExists("Save password for ","") Then
        WinActivate("Save password for ")
        Send("{TAB}")
        Send("{SPACE}")
    EndIf
EndIf

Exit
```

Compile the script to be an executable program as **ProxyAuth.exe**.

The program will receive two parameters : username and password.
With parameters, you can use dynamic username & password in your C# script.

Then you need to use the program in C# code as below :

```
ChromeOptions ChromeOptions = new ChromeOptions();

Proxy proxy = new Proxy();
proxy.Kind = ProxyKind.Manual;
proxy.IsAutoDetect = false;
proxy.SslProxy = $"{ProxyIP}:{ProxyPort}";
proxy.HttpProxy = $"{ProxyIP}:{ProxyPort}";
ChromeOptions.Proxy = proxy;
ChromeOptions.AddArgument("ignore-certificate-errors");

Driver = new ChromeDriver(ChromeOptions);
Driver.Navigate().GoToUrl(Url);

string cmd = string.Format($"{ProxyUsername} {ProxyPassword}");
Process proc = new Process();
proc.StartInfo.FileName = "ProxyAuth.exe";
proc.StartInfo.Arguments = cmd;
proc.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
proc.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
proc.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
proc.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;

proc.Start();
```

You will need to use **OpenQA.Selenium**, **OpenQA.Selenium.Chrome**, and **System.Diagnostics** namespaces.

** **EDIT** **

If you interested in using AutoIt, you can also use their library in NuGet. Just search in "Manage NuGet Packages" : AutoIt. Choose the one and only one AutoIt package shown and install it.

With this library, you don't need to create **ProxyAuth.exe** application as described above.

You can use the AutoIt library and make modifications in the C# code :

```
ChromeOptions ChromeOptions = new ChromeOptions();

Proxy proxy = new Proxy();
proxy.Kind = ProxyKind.Manual;
proxy.IsAutoDetect = false;
proxy.SslProxy = $"{ProxyIP}:{ProxyPort}";
proxy.HttpProxy = $"{ProxyIP}:{ProxyPort}";
ChromeOptions.Proxy = proxy;
ChromeOptions.AddArgument("ignore-certificate-errors");

Driver = new ChromeDriver(ChromeOptions);
Driver.Navigate().GoToUrl(Url);

// use the AutoIt library
AutoItX.AutoItSetOption("WinTitleMatchMode", 2);

AutoItX.WinWaitActive("- Google Chrome", "", 10);
AutoItX.WinActivate("- Google Chrome");

AutoItX.Send(ProxyUsername);
AutoItX.Send("{TAB}");
AutoItX.Send(ProxyPassword);
AutoItX.Send("{ENTER}");

// dismiss save password prompt
AutoItX.WinWaitActive("Save password for ", "", 10);
AutoItX.WinActivate("Save password for ");

AutoItX.Send("{TAB}");
AutoItX.Send("{SPACE}");
```

Comment: Thank you it helped, but in my case, I am running multiple Chromes parallelly and there are scenarios when Chrome is not always on top, so is there any way I can send AutoIt commands to specific app instances?

Answer (score 0):

Answered in another thread [C# Selenium Proxy Authentication with Chrome Driver](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69851056/4527678).

Main idea - use [Selenium 4.0 and BiDi APIs](https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/webdriver/bidi_apis/).