# Using Socks5 proxy server in Selenium Firefox on C# (.NET Core 3.1) cause Timeout

Tags: c#, selenium, firefox, .net-core, proxy

I have a local proxy server running on `127.0.0.1:5001` which is forwarded to a remote server using SSH. It should be used by my Selenium Firefox instance. [This method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12186579/c-sharp-selenium-webdriver-firefox-profile-using-proxy-with-authentication) is deprecated, Selenium recomments to use the `FirefoxOptions` instead. So I tried the following simple POC and modified it to use a socks instead of http proxy:

```
using OpenQA.Selenium;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Firefox;
using System;

namespace SeleniumProxyTest {
    class Program {
        static void Main(string[] args) {
            var opts = new FirefoxOptions();
            var proxy = new Proxy();
            proxy.Kind = ProxyKind.Manual;
            proxy.SocksProxy = "127.0.0.1:5002";
            opts.Proxy = proxy;

            var driver = new FirefoxDriver(opts);
            driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("https://www.perfect-privacy.com/de/tests/check-ip");

            Console.WriteLine("Finished");
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

But after some time, an exception occurs during creation of the `FirefoxDriver`:

> InvalidArgumentError: Expected "socksVersion" to be a positive integer, got [object Undefined] undefined (SessionNotCreated)

But the `OpenQA.Selenium.Proxy` class doesn't contain any attribute related to the socks version.

### What I have tried

#### Setting the protocol in the proxy url

```
proxy.SocksProxy = "socks5://127.0.0.1:5002";
```

Resulting in an error that no procotol should be specified:

> OpenQA.Selenium.WebDriverException: "socksProxy must not contain a scheme: socks5://127.0.0.1:5002"

#### Setting `socksVersion` as settings in the constructor

I found that the constructor of the `Proxy` class accepts a dictionary of settings. Since the exception expects a specific property, I tried to set the version there:

```
var proxySettings = new Dictionary<string, object>() { { "socksVersion", 5 } };
var proxy = new Proxy(proxySettings);
```

Since Selenium is open source, I could confirm this assumption by [taking a look in the `Proxy.cs` class](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/64447d4b03f6986337d1ca8d8b6476653570bcc1/dotnet/src/webdriver/Proxy.cs#L175) where the version is fetched from the provided settings dictionary. So my code should work.

Now I got rid of the `socketVersion` error. However, it still doesn't work, now it throws a time ouf in the `new FirefoxDriver` line:

> OpenQA.Selenium.WebDriverException: "The HTTP request to the remote WebDriver server for URL http://localhost:32904/session timed out after 60 seconds."

The Firefox window of Selenium is opened far before that exception, but no navigation is done and the proxy settings are set to the default *use the proxy settings of the system*.

[image]

Since the Firefox window was opened and it says `Listening on 127.0.0.1:45089` in the console, I thought that the local communication between my .NET Core application and the geckodriver doesn't work because of the proxy. So I added exceptions:

```
proxy.AddBypassAddresses(new string[] { "localhost", "127.0.0.1" });
```

Those doesn't seem to help. Also still no proxy entry in the network config as shown on the screenshot above.

#### Using HTTP proxy works

Strangely it works when I setup a HTTP instead of Socks5 proxy on 127.0.0.1 without any exception rules for local addresses.

**Edit: Preferences also doesn't work**

I translated [this example](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/issues/7803) to C#, which sets the proxy directly as prefernece in the profile:

```
var profile = new FirefoxProfile();
profile.SetPreference("network.proxy.type", 1);
profile.SetPreference("network.proxy.socks", "127.0.0.1");
profile.SetPreference("network.proxy.socks_port", 5002);
profile.SetPreference("network.proxy.socks_remote_dns", true);

var opts = new FirefoxOptions();
opts.Profile = profile;
var driver = new FirefoxDriver(opts);
```

Now Firefox navigates to the URL without timeout, but no proxy is set or used.

**So I'm wondering why it doesn't work on Socks5 proxies and what I need to change to make it work?**

Used package versions:

```
<PackageReference Include="Selenium.WebDriver" Version="3.141.0" />
<PackageReference Include="Selenium.WebDriver.GeckoDriver" Version="0.29.1" />
```

Comment: Your URL is HTTPS (secure).  So the version of Sock5 may not support the TLS version that is being used by the server.  The Sock5 version at GitHub is 4 years old and probably doesn't support TLS 1.2.

Comment: @jdweng But the problem now is that no proxy settings were set in Firefox when setting a socks proxy. The timeout exception already occurs when initializing the `FirefoxDriver`. To proof this, I uncommented `driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("https://www.perfect-privacy.com/de/tests/check-ip");` and still got the timeout exception. It seems that Selenium can't communicate to the Firefox instance to tell him where to navigate (it shows a blank page)

Comment: Use a sniffer like wireshark and capture the TLS version that is being used when it works and doesn't work.  The default version of TLS is probably wrong.  Check your setting in the browser and see what versions of TLS are checked.  Make sure you only use TLS 1.2 or 1.3.  Other versions of TLS are obsolete.